# Did Prof Trelawney change Harry's grade after Buckbeak's escape?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry takes his Divination exam in the third book, he pretends to see Buckbeak in the crystal ball. Trelawney is initially impressed, believing Harry to be "seeing" the outcome of Buckbeak's doomed trial, and writes it down. When Harry says that Buckbeak is not decapitated but flying away, Trelawney is disappointed as she, like everyone else, knows Buckbeak will be found guilty and thus thinks Harry is wrong and so she writes this down.

Later, however, after Buckbeak does escape, is there any canon evidence Harry got a good grade on the exam, which implies Trelawney changed Harry's grade after the escape (realizing his prediction was correct)?

Comment: Not that I ever could find anything along those lines, but knowing Trelawney as we do, I doubt she would let herself be influenced by something as mundane as reality while grading a student. More than likely she will say she had predicted everybody's answers and grades at the beginning of the year anyway, so why would she change it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alas, no mention is made of it.**

This is all we hear of Harry’s exam results at the end of third year:

> The exam results came out on the last day of term. Harry, Ron, and Hermione had passed every subject. Harry was amazed that he had got through Potions. He had a shrewd suspicion that Dumbledore might have stepped in to stop Snape failing him on purpose. Snape’s behavior toward Harry over the past week had been quite alarming. Harry wouldn’t have thought it possible that Snape’s dislike for him could increase, but it certainly had.
>
> — *Prisoner of Azkaban*, chapter 22 (*Owl Post Again*)

We know that he passed Divination, but no more detail than that.

I suspect Trelawney is much more influenced by your air of mystique, ability to use the right terms and willingness to predict the death of your classmates than whether your predictions actually come true.

If you ask me, Trelawney is just impressed because Harry has foreseen death and doom.

If Trelawney was in the habit of having grades reflect the truth of reality, then she’d be going back to update all of Harry and Ron’s homework grades in *Goblet of Fire*, as many of their homework predictions [eventually turn out to happen](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Divination_(class)#Behind_the_scenes). But that doesn’t seem like Trelawney to me.